# Using dynamic components to render Angular attributes to svg

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg, angular-directive

I would like to render dynamically `matTooltip` directive to SVG element .

I'm trying to use dynamic components in Angular in order to render a component with `matTooltip` directive inside a `circle` element

But tooltip is not getting render. I think that the template reference is not well placed

here's the [tutorial](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d) I used

A bug reproduction [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vgjjl-dyap5s?file=app/tooltip-overview-example.html)

Comment: check your console elements there should be your component `app-root > svg > tool-tip > div.mattooltip ` since div or tool-tip are not valid sag children they won't show up as html

Comment: I have replaced the div with svg file , nothing shows up